# How to install Linux on a PowerPC?

Tags: linux, mac, installation, boot-camp

I have a Powerbook G4 running 10.5.8. How can I put Linux on there? Boot camp? Anything? Also, where can I get a free download of Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see which available linux distros work on your ppc computer here: [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?category=Desktop&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=powerpc&status=Active)

I'd recommend Ubuntu. Download the ISO to your computer, burn it onto a CD using Disk Utility and reboot with the CD in the drive while holding down `c` to boot from the CD.

Comment: @emgee Then after I boot from it, how do I install it? Then can I later run it without the CD? And which version do I want? 10.10?

Comment: The installation guide @AndrejaKo linked is a good start. Also check this link for safely resizing your existing partitions: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-89960.html

Comment: And yes, you after you install, you will not need the cd in the drive.

Comment: @emgee So afterwards, all I have to do is hold down C?

Comment: I'd try 10.10 to start. Your computer might be underpowered for it though, so if it's slow, you might try an earlier version.

Comment: @Emgee and is this the same as bootcamping? Also, is it possible to bootcamp Windows AND Linux both on a mac? What comes up after holding down C? Is it similar to when you press command + Tab?

Comment: As far as I know (and I may be wrong) Bootcamp is only for Windows on OS X. However, the process you are doing here is very similar. Holding down c tells the Mac to boot from CD. If you hold down Option, it lets you choose which drive to boot from.

Comment: If you have an Intel Mac, you can triple boot. You can not natively boot Windows on a G4.

Comment: @emgee Do I have to partition my drive first?

Comment: I would resize it as the first step.

Comment: +1 for recommending Ubuntu, I did it long time ago with the PPC distro Ubuntu 6.10 and it was working well. I managed as well to install a second IDE harddisk after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any first hand experience, but here are some interesting sources of information:

- [Installation guide for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/index.html)
- [Installation guide for Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-ppc.xml?full=1)

The Ubuntu guide is more focused on the installation of Ubuntu itself, while the Gentoo guide contains lots of information on how to do things by hand. This is useful because from time to time GUI utilities can cause problems which sometimes may not be easily solved.